# Como agregar fuentes de letra a un proyecto de windows forms hecho en Visual Studio a través del lenguaje C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, fuentes

Muy buenas comunidad.
Uso VisualStudio Community 2017, lenguaje C#, estoy queriendo implementar nuevas fuentes de letras para un proyecto. Si bien pensaba que era algo simple usar o agregar fuentes de letras nuevas al proyecto, después de seguir varios tutoriales presentados en distintas plataformas no pude aún dar con lo que necesito.

Si bien en principio trate de agregar las fuentes a las fuentes locales de mi computadora y usarlas desde visual studio, el IDE me respondió que solo acepta aquellas fuentes que son de tipo TrueType (más allá de que sabía que era una mala práctica, porque la computadora donde voy a instalar el sistema no tiene esa fuente, ni la necesidad de que instale la misma). Por lo que me puse a navegar por internet y entre varios foros encontré dos tutoriales que seguí sin éxito para solucionar el problema.

1. Al agregar las fuentes en una carpeta dentro del proyecto y cambiarle las propiedades para que se carguen con la compilación (imagen 1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa se rompe antes de cargarse y me muestra el siguiente error:
'(Directorio del archivo)' es un archivo binario en vez de uno de texto (imagen 2)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En uno de los tutoriales encontré este extracto de código:

   System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
   privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\Documents and Settings\somefont.ttf");
   System.Drawing.Font font = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12);
   label1.Font = font;

Al implementarlo me daba los siguientes errores sobre el atributo "privateFonts":
"Un inicializador de campo no puede hacer referencia al campo, método o propiedad no estáticos"
"no existe en el contexto actual"
(imagen 3)

[image: imagen 3]

Para solucionar esos problemas lo que hice fue inicializar la variable font dentro del constructor del windows form, como se ve en la siguiente imagen (imagen 4)

[image: imagen 4]

El problema está en cuando corro al programa, en tiempo de ejecución el programa se rompe devolviéndome un error de tipo "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" y me aclara: "Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz." sobre la instancia de la variable font (imagen 5)

[image: imagen 5]

Al margen de los errores me interesa poder implementar el uso de fuentes nuevas, por lo que se agradece cualquier información al respecto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo parece indicar que estas intentando acceder a la colección `privateFonts.Families` cuando todavia no has cargado nigun archivo de fuente al objeto `privateFonts` si esa así es logico que `privateFonts.Families` este vacia y por tanto el indice cero esta fuera del rango, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente.

```
//CONSTRUCTOR
public AdminBase()
{
   InitilizeComponent();
   g = new Gestor();
   //Primero agregar el archivo fuentes
   privateFonts.AddFontFile("./Fuentes/Chapaza.ttf");
   //Despues de cargar el archivo fuente creas la fuente
   font = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12);

   ActivarPaneles(2);
   PersonalizarDataGrid(gdClientes);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no entendía la lógica del algoritmo, por desconocimiento de las clases.  
Solucioné el problema con lo que sugeriste!
Saludos!

Comment: @F.GabrielSosaRozzi Por nada estamos aquí para ayudar, si te sivió, te agradeceria que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada y si lo crees que la puntearas.